# Create forwarding email address for mailing to members of a group

Tags: email

Is it possible to create a custom email address which forwards to all members of the organisation, or all members of a group? Perhaps via Inbound Mail Handling? *edit - perhaps Civi or Drupal Rules?*

This would enable a non-tech savvy Secretary to email all members (or another group) from their own email client via the custom email address rather than via CiviMail interface, and each email only go to current members of the organisation.

Comment: I tweaked the tags as 'member of group' and 'civimember' are not same thing so didn't seem like 'civimember' was helpful.

Comment: i like the question. it may help to mention the CMS since eg Drupal Rules might be part of the consideration. I think CiviRules now has some mailing ability - so the chain might be something like - send an email which triggers creation of an activity which then triggers an email to the associated group (assuming you are thinking one inbound email per group).

Comment: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.emailapi is the civirules addition if that is the route to go. just thinking aloud

Comment: Also reminds me of the [CiviCRM-Sympa integration/extension](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.sympasync). On the plus side, Sympa has a lot of options for defining the list's behavior. On the downside, it's only handy if you're using Sympa, and I haven't tried the extension in a long time.

Comment: Neither of the above suggestions work, scheduled emails do not send at all, no matter how they are supposed to be triggered (looks like this is an ongoing bug), and Civi rules does not let you email groups, only one contact. does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: @crowdfundinxmr if you do not have Scheduled Reminders sending, the suggest you open a separate ticket as is a separate problem

Answer (score 2):

This problem has two parts - getting the email into Civi, and sending it out again to people in a group.  The first part is definitely going to be done with Inbound Email Handling if the person will be using their email client.

For the second part, I like Tim's idea of integrating with Sympa or Mailman, but unless you need the full-blown list management software, it seems like overkill.

Pete's CiviRules answer should be correct; however, just this week I tried doing almost the exact same thing (redirect incoming SMS to a team's email) but I couldn't get the tokens to work.  My client was on a tight budget so rather than troubleshoot I just repurposed [an existing extension](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/coop.palantetech.smsemailnotify).  I would try this CiviRules approach first.

Another approach would be Scheduled Reminders (**Administer menu » Communications » Scheduled Reminders**).  You could set a reminder to trigger on an "Inbound Email" activity, and use the **Select Group** dropdown to pick the group.  Your token would just be `{activity.details}` to pick up the message body.  If you do this, you should make sure your cron runs reasonably frequently.  You would also want to increase the frequency of the *Process Inbound Email* and *Send Scheduled Reminders* jobs under **Administer menu » System Settings » Scheduled Jobs**.

Comment: Presumably {activity.details} would pick up all the text in the email, but would not forward attachments? We could do attachments with links, but that may not be helping the Secretary as much.

Comment: Yeah - if you want attachments you're going to need an extension to handle it.